# How do I set Spring properties in run configuration in Intellij

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I have the following code...

```
@Service
public class PropertiesService {
    ...
    @Value("external.config.active") private String useExternalConfig
```

So in intellij I set the VM Options to...

```
-Dexternal.config.active=true
```

But when I debug in the application `this.useExternalConfig.equals("external.config.active")` is true.

What do I have to do to set a Spring property in the run configuration for IJ

**Update** I see it being supplied in the java command...

> /.../java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:53192,suspend=y,server=n **-Dexternal.config.active=true** -javaagent:/.../Caches/IdeaIC2018.1/groovyHotSwap/gragent.jar -javaagent:/.../Caches/IdeaIC2018.1/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar=file:/private/var/folders/3d/5f6dvvs573zg3ydvxbd0b0h40000gn/T/capture2.props -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath

Comment: Try to do it in "Command Line" instead. I have the following line in that field: `spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=dev ` and it works

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, I also need to be able to debug will using command line affect debugging?

Comment: I also don't see a command line option in my run configuration.

Answer (score 1):

`@Value` takes a value expression `${...}` or a SpEL expression `#{...}` as you haven't provided any of those the value as is will be used. To substitute a property you can use a value expression `${name.of.property}`.

Or if you really like hardcore you can use SpEL `#{@environment.getProperty('name.of.property')}`. You see the value expression is easier.

Comment: So does that mean the former is just syntactic sugar for the later?

Comment: No it isn't... A value expression is something different then a SpEL expression. The latter is a EL expression language and you could basically create a whole programming line in that , you cannot do that with a value expression.

Answer (score 0):

This does seem to work...

```
@Value("${external.config.active}")
```

based on...

```
The actual value expression: e.g. "#{systemProperties.myProp}".
```

This is strange so if anyone can explain it further they get the check.